# Google Datastore: get_by_id with an ancestor

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to retrieve an entity from a ndb Datastore
I know the id and an ancestor (not the parent!)

Although this query works fine when knowing the parent

```
 Entity.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('entityId')),parent=entityParent.key)
```

The ancestor version is apparently not supported

How should I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a get for that, since that is only for *exact* keys and you don't have one. You need to do an ancestor query:

```
Entity.query(Query.id==int(self.request.get('entityId')), ancestor=ancestor.key)
```